# Should the action or store be responsible for transforming data when using React + Flux?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

When using React and Flux, it's standard practice to make API calls from actions, and then store the resulting data in a Store class. But who should be responsible for transforming that data after it's been stored?

Example: I've got an `EntryStore` that keeps hold of objects representing shopping list items. I have a number of filters that I can apply to them (e.g "show only `dairy`"). I currently have this working by calling `EntryActions.filterEntries('dairy')`, which the dispatcher then passes to `EntryStore` where a `_filterEntries(tag)` method transforms the`EntryStore._entries` array. Is this considered best practice? Should the action itself transform the list of entries, then pass it to `EntryStore` to simply save? How dumb should the Store be in this case?

Comment: Couldn't you just filter when the view renders? Or use CSS? Seems overkill to use flux's dataflow in this instance, IMHO. I sometimes filter in the store, but only when the data is static and right after the store has received all the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you're right! In Flux, we want to keep the data structure flat, and let any data manipulation occur in the Stores themselves. The data-flow is essentially:

```
Component --> (actions) --> Dispatcher --> (callback) ---> Stores -----+
Ʌ                                                                      |
|                                                                      V
+-- ("change" event handlers) --------------------- (change events) ---+
```

Mutation of data has to happen through calling actions from your views/components. The data stores listen on these actions and mutate the data within the store (including filtering, and any other data mutations or logic you may need)

Comment: I'm little hung up on this example. Let's assume no immutable JS for the moment. Say I filter my store to only include dairy. Cool, I now have a dairy-specific store. Now I want to filter it to "meats". If I've changed out the contents of the store, how am I going to filter everything again?

Comment: Ideally you should be using immutable data structures, since that data flow model aligns well with ideas of Flux and React (Facebook even has a dedicated immutable data structure just for React and Flux: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/). Otherwise you would need to filter it on the view via React components (which isn't wrong, but just more data-logic in your view layer).