# Using Flux to build an edit form, who actually POSTs data to the server: actions, stores, views?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I have found a lot of resources, blogs, and opinions on how to fetch data for React and Flux, but much less on writing data to the server.  Can someone please provide a rationale and some sample code for the "preferred" approach, in the context of building a simple edit form that persists changes to a RESTful web API?

Specifically, which of the Flux boxes should call `$.post`, where is the `ActionCreator.receiveItem()` invoked (and what does it do), and what is in the store's registered method?

Relevant links:

- [Should the action or store be responsible for transforming data when using React + Flux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494492/should-the-action-or-store-be-responsible-for-transforming-data-when-using-react)
- [Should flux stores, or actions (or both) touch external services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630611/should-flux-stores-or-actions-or-both-touch-external-services)
- [Where should ajax request be made in Flux app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632415/where-should-ajax-request-be-made-in-flux-app)

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**

- Your form component should retrieve its state from Store, create "update" action on user inputs, and call a "save" action on form submit.
- The action creators will perform the POST request and will trigger a "save_success" action or "save_error" action depending on the request results.

**Long answer via implementation example**

*apiUtils/BarAPI.js*

```
var Request = require('./Request'); //it's a custom module that handles request via superagent wrapped in Promise
var BarActionCreators = require('../actions/BarActionCreators');

var _endpoint = 'http://localhost:8888/api/bars/';

module.exports = {

    post: function(barData) {
        BarActionCreators.savePending();
        Request.post(_endpoint, barData).then (function(res) {
            if (res.badRequest) { //i.e response returns code 400 due to validation errors for example
                BarActionCreators.saveInvalidated(res.body);
            }
            BarActionCreators.savedSuccess(res.body);
        }).catch( function(err) { //server errors
            BarActionCreators.savedError(err);
        });
    },

    //other helpers out of topic for this answer

};
```

*actions/BarActionCreators.js*

```
var AppDispatcher = require('../dispatcher/AppDispatcher');
var ActionTypes = require('../constants/BarConstants').ActionTypes;
var BarAPI = require('../apiUtils/VoucherAPI');

module.exports = {

    save: function(bar) {
        BarAPI.save(bar.toJSON());
    },

    saveSucceed: function(response) {
        AppDispatcher.dispatch({
            type: ActionTypes.BAR_SAVE_SUCCEED,
            response: response
        });
    },

    saveInvalidated: function(barData) {
        AppDispatcher.dispatch({
            type: ActionTypes.BAR_SAVE_INVALIDATED,
            response: response
        })
    },

    saveFailed: function(err) {
        AppDispatcher.dispatch({
            type: ActionTypes.BAR_SAVE_FAILED,
            err: err
        });
    },

    savePending: function(bar) {
        AppDispatcher.dispatch({
            type: ActionTypes.BAR_SAVE_PENDING,
            bar: bar
        });
    }

    rehydrate: function(barId, field, value) {
        AppDispatcher.dispatch({
            type: ActionTypes.BAR_REHYDRATED,
            barId: barId,
            field: field,
            value: value
        });
    },

};
```

*stores/BarStore.js*

```
var assign = require('object-assign');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var Immutable = require('immutable');

var AppDispatcher = require('../dispatcher/AppDispatcher');
var ActionTypes = require('../constants/BarConstants').ActionTypes;
var BarAPI = require('../apiUtils/BarAPI')
var CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';

var _bars = Immutable.OrderedMap();

class Bar extends Immutable.Record({
    'id': undefined,
    'name': undefined,
    'description': undefined,
    'save_status': "not saved" //better to use constants here
}) {

    isReady() {
        return this.id != undefined //usefull to know if we can display a spinner when the Bar is loading or the Bar's data if it is ready.
    }

    getBar() {
        return BarStore.get(this.bar_id);
    }
}

function _rehydrate(barId, field, value) {
    //Since _bars is an Immutable, we need to return the new Immutable map. Immutable.js is smart, if we update with the save values, the same reference is returned.
    _bars = _bars.updateIn([barId, field], function() {
        return value;
    });
}


var BarStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {

    get: function(id) {
        if (!_bars.has(id)) {
            BarAPI.get(id); //not defined is this example
            return new Bar(); //we return an empty Bar record for consistency
        }
        return _bars.get(id)
    },

    getAll: function() {
        return _bars.toList() //we want to get rid of keys and just keep the values
    },

    Bar: Bar,

    emitChange: function() {
        this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
    },

    addChangeListener: function(callback) {
        this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    },

    removeChangeListener: function(callback) {
        this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    },

});

var _setBar = function(barData) {
    _bars = _bars.set(barData.id, new Bar(barData));
};

BarStore.dispatchToken = AppDispatcher.register(function(action) {
    switch (action.type)
    {   

        case ActionTypes.BAR_REHYDRATED:
            _rehydrate(
                action.barId,
                action.field,
                action.value
            );
            BarStore.emitChange();
            break;

        case ActionTypes.BAR_SAVE_PENDING:
            _bars = _bars.updateIn([action.bar.id, "save_status"], function() {
                return "saving";
            });
            BarStore.emitChange();
            break;

        case ActionTypes.BAR_SAVE_SUCCEED:
            _bars = _bars.updateIn([action.bar.id, "save_status"], function() {
                return "saved";
            });
            BarStore.emitChange();
            break;

        case ActionTypes.BAR_SAVE_INVALIDATED:
            _bars = _bars.updateIn([action.bar.id, "save_status"], function() {
                return "invalid";
            });
            BarStore.emitChange();
            break;

        case ActionTypes.BAR_SAVE_FAILED:
            _bars = _bars.updateIn([action.bar.id, "save_status"], function() {
                return "failed";
            });
            BarStore.emitChange();
            break;

        //many other actions outside the scope of this answer

        default:
            break;
    }
});

module.exports = BarStore;
```

*components/BarList.react.js*

```
var React = require('react/addons');
var Immutable = require('immutable');

var BarListItem = require('./BarListItem.react');
var BarStore = require('../stores/BarStore');

function getStateFromStore() {
    return {
        barList: BarStore.getAll(),
    };
}

module.exports = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return getStateFromStore();
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        BarStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        BarStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
    },

    render: function() {
        var barItems = this.state.barList.toJS().map(function (bar) {
            // We could pass the entire Bar object here
            // but I tend to keep the component not tightly coupled
            // with store data, the BarItem can be seen as a standalone
            // component that only need specific data
            return <BarItem
                        key={bar.get('id')}
                        id={bar.get('id')}
                        name={bar.get('name')}
                        description={bar.get('description')}/>
        });

        if (barItems.length == 0) {
            return (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            )
        }

        return (
            <div>
                {barItems}
            </div>
        )

    },

    _onChange: function() {
        this.setState(getStateFromStore();
    }

});
```

*components/BarListItem.react.js*

```
var React = require('react/addons');
var ImmutableRenderMixin = require('react-immutable-render-mixin')
var Immutable = require('immutable');

module.exports = React.createClass({

    mixins: [ImmutableRenderMixin],

    // I use propTypes to explicitly telling
    // what data this component need. This 
    // component is a standalone component
    // and we could have passed an entire
    // object such as {id: ..., name, ..., description, ...}
    // since we use all the datas (and when we use all the data it's
    // a better approach since we don't want to write dozens of propTypes)
    // but let's do that for the example's sake 
    propTypes: {
        id: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        description: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }

    render: function() {

        return (
            <li> //we should wrapped the following p's in a Link to the editing page of the Bar record with id = this.props.id. Let's assume that's what we did and when we click on this <li> we are redirected to edit page which renders a BarDetail component
                <p>{this.props.id}</p>
                <p>{this.props.name}</p>
                <p>{this.props.description}</p>
            </li>
        )

    }

});
```

*components/BarDetail.react.js*

```
var React = require('react/addons');
var ImmutableRenderMixin = require('react-immutable-render-mixin')
var Immutable = require('immutable');

var BarActionCreators = require('../actions/BarActionCreators');

module.exports = React.createClass({

    mixins: [ImmutableRenderMixin],

    propTypes: {
        id: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        description: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    },

    handleSubmit: function(event) {
        //Since we keep the Bar data up to date with user input
        //we can simply save the actual object in Store.
        //If the user goes back without saving, we could display a 
        //"Warning : item not saved" 
        BarActionCreators.save(this.props.id);
    },

    handleChange: function(event) {
        BarActionCreators.rehydrate(
            this.props.id,
            event.target.name, //the field we want to rehydrate
            event.target.value //the updated value
        );
    },

    render: function() {

        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSumit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    value={this.props.name}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <textarea
                    name="description"
                    value={this.props.description}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <input
                    type="submit"
                    defaultValue="Submit"/>
            </form>
        )

    },

});
```

With this basic example, whenever the user edits a Bar item via the form in `BarDetail` component, the underlying `Bar` record will be maintained up to date locally and when the form is submitted we try to save it on the server. That's it :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Components/Views are used to display data and fire events
2. Actions are tied to the events (onClick, onChange...) and are used to communicate with resources and dispatch events once the promise has been resolved or failed. Make sure you have at least two events, one for success and one for ajax failed.
3. Stores are subscribed to the events dispatcher is dispatching. Once data is received stores are updating the values which are stored and emitting changes.
4. Components/Views are subscribed to the stores and are re-rendering once the change has happened.

[Should flux stores, or actions (or both) touch external services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630611/should-flux-stores-or-actions-or-both-touch-external-services) approach is what seems natural to me.

Also there are cases when you need to trigger some action as a result of some other action being triggered, this is where you can trigger actions from a relevant store, which results store and views being updated.